# How to get Webkit bugs fixed?

Tags: c++, open-source, webkit

Webkit has a few bugs that prevent our software from running in this browser (and Safari/Chrome/etc). We don't have sufficient C++ knowledge to fix the bugs ourselves, but we're certainly willing to fund the development and do extensive testing of the patches. What would be the best way to proceed?

I was thinking of submitting a project per bug in one of the RentACoder or [alike](http://www.geekpoint.net/internet-marketing/5886-70-alternatives-rentacoder.html) sites. Which site would be best for this particular work?

Most bugs are related to standard compliance, so I expect Safari and Chrome to copy the patches once webkit accepts them. Is there anything I can do to accelerate that process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 9):

I don't think c++ expertise is required in order to contribute.

Write a detailed error report. Create a comprehensive set of test cases, with some sort of reference rendering. Put all of this on a webpage, and then create a bug report (or comment on an existing one) on the WebKit bug tracker.

Read more about [tests](http://webkit.org/quality/testwriting.html) (and wait, there is even [more](http://webkit.org/quality/reduction.html)), or more about [reporting bugs](http://webkit.org/quality/reporting.html).